# How to calculate Rotation matrix for Rotation from GPS Co-ordinate system to SLAM Co-ordinate system

Tags: gps, robotics, rotational-matrices, orb, slam

In our SLAM algorithm, we want to rotate GPS co-ordinates to SLAM co-ordinate system so that those GPS positions can be used for bundle adjustment in monocular SLAM (Scale correction).

We have used following procedure for rotation.

1. Convert Lat, Long, `Att` GPS co-ordinates to `XYZ` co-ordinate using `Geoconverter` library. (Resetting origin same as SLAM co-ordinate's origin)
2. Therefore, calculate rotation matrix between `XYZ` GPS co-ordinates and SLAM co-ordinates using [`rodrigues` rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) formula for the first vector after origin.
3. Then, for each `XYZ` GPS position use the rotation matrix to calculate the GPS co-ordinates in SLAM co-ordinate system.

However, the results are not as expected, the GPS co-ordinate plane does not align with SLAM co-ordinates, hence bundle adjustment fails.

To check the actual position of the GPS co-ordinates after rotation, we plotted them (as shown below).
[Front view (GPS(olive), SLAM(blue), `MapPoints`(black))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHWgz.png)
[Without `MapPoints`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gytBQ.png)
[Side view to understand GPS and SLAM are in different plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laAnK.png)
[Side view with `MapPoints`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBjbA.png)
[Side view different angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u46jN.png)

Can you point out the mistake in the process or suggest an alternate process to align GPS data.

Thanks

Saurabh Kumar